# Regular expression to find all occurrences of words between substrings

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a huge string (it's the inner HTML of the whole webpage).

There are many sub strings:

```
href="/department/company/3434?        
href="/department/company/254888?    
href="/department/company/87879?
```

etc..

How to get all occurrences between `"href="/department/company/`  and "?" ??
So, basically i need to get all ids which are between the sub strings above.

The result:

```
arr = [3434, 254888, 87879];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use match all with a regular expression to extract this out:

```js
const testString = `
some other stuff here href="/department/company/3434?        
href="/department/company/254888?    <p>Yes indeed</p>
<h1 href="/department/company/87879?>A title or something</h1> 
`;

const matches = testString.matchAll(/department\/company\/([^?]+)\?/gm);

for (let match of matches) {
  console.log(match[1]);
}
```